# Como excluir a primeira linha em um arquivo CSV python

Tags: python, pandas

Preciso excluir a primeira linha de um arquivo csv, que é o cabeçalho e não tem uso. Aṕos a exclusão da linha o script deve gravar com o mesmo nome o arquivo csv (sem a linha excluída). Procurei pelo modulo panda e o próprio python e não encontrei. Podem ajudar um entusiasta?

Exemplo:

```
ACYPR556- VALORES UTILIZADOS P/ CÁLCULO DO ÍNDICE,,,ANO BASE - 017,EXERCÍCIO - 2018,VIGÊNCIA - 2019,
CODIGO,MUNICIPIO,V.A ANTERIOR,V.A ATUAL,RECEITA PROPRIA,POPULACAO,AREA(KM2)
00500-2,ACORIZAL,"37644152,27","60575938,58","812558,81",5269,850
01000-6,AGUA BOA,"710615986,43","735690297,77","14285458,94",24501,7410
```

Answer (score 6):

Para salvar um dataframe sem o cabeçalho, basta fazer

```
df.to_csv('arquivo.csv', header=False)
```

Caso também queira remover os índices

```
df.to_csv('arquivo.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Assim, se você tiver um CSV do tipo

```
id,nome
1,Anderson
2,Carlos
3,Woss
```

Ao fazer

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df.to_csv('data.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Você terá:

```
1,Anderson
2,Carlos
3,Woss
```

---

Sem utilizar o Pandas, você pode percorrer as linhas do arquivo CSV ignorando a primeira, referente ao cabeçalho, e escrevendo as demais em um novo arquivo, bem como [respondido pelo AlexCiuffa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379618/5878), porém, da forma que ele implementou o conteúdo do arquivo inteiro ficará armazenado em memória. Se o arquivo CSV for muito grande, isso consumirá recursos desnecessários da máquina e poderá, inclusive, travá-la. A melhor forma de implementar é tirar proveito do gerador que a função `open` retorna, mantendo apenas uma linha do arquivo em memória por vez:

```
with open('arquivo_com_cabeçalho.csv') as stream,
     open('arquivo_sem_cabeçalho.csv', 'w') as output:
    next(stream)  # Ignora a primeira linha do arquivo de entrada
    for line in stream:
        output.write(line)
```

Comment: Obrigado! Perfeito.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi na documentação você pode utilizar o proprio [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) do **pandas** para fazer um ignorar a linha.

```
df = pd.read_csv( "meu.csv", skiprows=[0] );
#                                      ^ lista com as linha que devem ser ignoradas
```

e para salvar em csv novamente usar o [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
df.to_csv( "meu-novo.csv" , index=False);
```

Comment: para pular mais de uma linha, saberia como?

Comment: Se você colocar `skiprows=20` ele vai pular as 20 primeiras linhas. Se você colocar uma lista Ex. `skiprows=[ 0, 2, 4, 10 ]`, ele vai pular as linhas de índice `0`, `2`, `4` e `10`

Answer (score 0):

Com Python apenas, é possível ler assim:

```
import csv

# Lê um CSV com o cabeçalho
with open("arquivo.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    #next(reader) # skip header
    data = [r for r in reader]

# Separa o cabeçalho e os dados
header = data[0]
data = data[1:]
```

Depois de realizar operações com os dados, podemos escrever assim:

```
with open("arquivo_modificado.csv", 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Como apontado pelo @Anderson nos comentários, não há necessidade de carregar todos os dados para a memória, principalmente se a quantidade de dados for muito grande. Podemos já abrir o arquivo e ler linha a linha, já alterando e salvando cada linha em outro csv.

```
with open("arquivo.csv") as arquivo_leitura:
    reader = csv.reader(arquivo_leitura)
    cabecalho = next(reader, None)

    with open("arquivo_modificado.csv", 'w') as arquivo_escrita:
        writer = csv.writer(arquivo_escrita)
        writer.writerow(cabecalho)

        for linha in reader:
            linha = realiza_operacao(linha)
            writer.writerow(linha)
```

Comment: Obrigado!!! Perfeito.

Comment: Recomendo que você faça a operação dentro de um mesmo gerenciador de contexto, sem armazenar todas as linhas do arquivo em memória. Com isso você terá um ganho em recursos bem considerável, principalmente se o arquivo em questão for muito grande.